# Error running npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am getting an error when running command 'npm install' in windows ...

Can anybody helps in fixing this issue...

Error shows when running npm install

```
51 verbose addNamed "2.3.1" is a plain semver version for gulp-connect

252 silly cache afterAdd gulp-connect@2.3.1

253 verbose afterAdd C:\Users\budPr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\gulp-connect\2.3.1\package\package.json not in flight; writing

254 verbose afterAdd C:\Users\budPr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\gulp-connect\2.3.1\package\package.json written

255 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, scandir 'C:\Users\budPr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ci-deploy-mfp\0.1.0\package.tgz'

255 verbose stack     at Error (native)
256 verbose cwd C:\mymobile\dev\Recruiter\build
257 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
258 error argv "C:\\tools\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\tools\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
259 error node v0.12.5
260 error npm  v2.11.2
261 error path C:\Users\budPr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ci-deploy-mfp\0.1.0\package.tgz

262 error code ENOENT
263 error errno -4058

264 error enoent ENOENT, scandir 'C:\Users\budPr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ci-deploy-mfp\0.1.0\package.tgz'

264 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

264 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.

265 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Thanks

Comment: provide more information like what you want to install from npm install or for what purpose you are using it...

Comment: You're on a very old version of node and npm, is updating an option for you?

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "build-common": "file:common",
    "ci-build-apps": "file:ci/build-apps",
    
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-help": "^1.6.0",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.2"
  },

Comment: I get the error with the  "build-common": "file:common", "ci-build-apps": on the dependency.. This worked last week .. not sure why it stopped working

Comment: I upgrade node and I still see the same issue.. Seem to be an issue install private modules...->>> 112 error addLocal Could not install C:\mymobile\dev\Recruiter\build\ci\deploy-mfp
113 error addLocal Could not install C:\mymobile\dev\Recruiter\build\ci\build-mapi
114 error addLocal Could not install C:\mymobile\dev\Recruiter\build\ci\build-web
115 error addLocal Could not install C:\mymobile\dev\Recruiter\build\common
116 error addLocal Could not install C:\mymobile\dev\Recruiter\build\ci\build-apps
117 error addLocal Could not install C:\mymobile\dev\Recruiter\build\ci\deploy-mapi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821698/npm-install-error-issue