# npm install error/issue

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, http-proxy, npm-config

I have already set proxy configurations in .npmrc file. 
Executing the npm install command gives me error as follows"

> $ npm install npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" npm ERR!
>   node v6.9.4 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established,
>   statusCode=400 npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with
>   npm itself npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
>   npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad
>   network settings. npm ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind
>   a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is
>   set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     D:\Pooja\quickstart\npm-debug.log

The .npmrc file in user folder contains following values

```
 1. registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
 2. proxy=http://proxy@domain.com:8080/
 3. http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy@domain.com:8080/
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: What does the file `D:\Pooja\quickstart\npm-debug.log` says?

Comment: info via:
88855 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     npm owner ls utf-8-validate
88855 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: There is likely additional logging output above.
88856 verbose stack Error: phantomjs@1.9.7-15 install: `node install.js`
88856 verbose stack Exit status 1
88856 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
88856 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
88856 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your proxy URL have '@' symbol in it? @ symbol separates the user ID and password from the URL. If it does, you can try using '%40' to replace it.

Also, it is https-proxy not http_proxy.

A correct config would look like -

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:8080/
https-proxy=https://username:password@proxydomain:8080/
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proxy

Comment: npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-promise/-/es6-promise-4.0.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established,
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-promise/-/es6-promise-4.0.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established,
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-promise/-/es6-promise-4.0.5.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\b

Comment: npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: Are you able to download the file https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-promise/-/es6-promise-4.0.5.tgz through your browser from behind the proxy? Also it will help if you provide the output of the command `npm config list` (make sure you mask the password). 

407 status code means your proxy did not authenticate your request. Make sure you are using a correct user id and password. Something is causing the proxy login to fail.

Comment: Ya it is working now.Problem was with the proxy address.I had entered incorrect proxy address. @manojtc thank you

Answer (score 1):

first give the command 
  and check if proxy is set,`npm config get proxy` if not set do the following        from command prompt

`npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy address:8080
  npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy address:8080`

and if password contains '@'in password, then replace it with '%40'

Answer (score 0):

Someone who comes from china may solve this problem by using Taobao mirror.

npm --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org install